# Child element only covering parent image

Tags: html, css

I have a menu where I want to have an active state and a hover state of the menu items. My problem is illustrated best in the two images. The green background color should only cover the dark orange area (Which is an image).

This is my menu now:

[image]

And this is how I want it to be:

[image]

Which way is best to cut the bottom of the green element to get this effect?

My code so far in JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/HC5qC/

CSS:

```
nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 96px;
    top: 37px;
}

nav li {
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: .9375em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 54px 15px 65px 15px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.current-menu-item a,
.current-menu-item a:hover {
    background: #79bd8f; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #79bd8f 30%, #00a388 99%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(30%,#79bd8f), color-stop(99%,#00a388)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #79bd8f 30%,#00a388 99%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #79bd8f 30%,#00a388 99%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #79bd8f 30%,#00a388 99%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #79bd8f 30%,#00a388 99%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#79bd8f', endColorstr='#00a388',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

nav a:hover {
    background: #6b1600;
    background: rgba(107, 22, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Please post your html markup and css in your question.

Comment: Is that an `<img>`..? is that a background..? is that a gradient..? how do we know..?

Comment: @HerrNilsson reduce the padding bottom in css for `.nav a`.

Comment: The question is updated now

Comment: I think it is necessary to alter the background menu and adding overflow: hidden;

Comment: for example in two layers

Comment: Using a bg image on the header pretty much means that this cannot be achieved with CSS.

Comment: i believe it's not possible.. i came this far: http://jsfiddle.net/HC5qC/7/ but this is not an answer to your problem

Comment: @vlrprbttst Me neither, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/52MHa/) might get you started.

I'll play around with it a bit more, to see how close we might get to what you want.

But the concept is to put an :after or :before, or an absolutely positioned "overlay" and be able to click to boxes behind.

CSS

```
.selector {
    width: 295px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}
.button1 {
    float: left;
    width: 32%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: blue;
}
.selector:after {
    content: '';
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 0px;
    transform: rotate(-3deg);
    background-color: red;
}
```